# How to crop multi images use list bounding box position in the file (python)?

Tags: python, json, image-processing, crop, bounding-box

I have a dataset of images.jpg and a file csv has values bounding box position is top, left, right, bottom. I use ubuntu OS and the python language.

Comment: Are the values rations from the height and width of the image?

Comment: Do you mean you have separate file with the crop position for each image file? Or you have one file with hundreds of crop positions in it and you somehow have to find which position is for which image? What are the formats of your files? How many files do you have? What OS do you use? Please add the code you have tried with too.

Comment: I had edited my post

Comment: See if you can write some Python to parse the CSV file first, read a line, extract the image filename and the left, right, top, bottom values and print them out. Then add that to your question and you will have done the hardest part.

Comment: By the way, please do not post pictures of your data - they are very hard to parse! Post the actual data instead.

Comment: You are going to have trouble parsing a CSV from that data as there are commas embedded in the JSON in the `bounding_box` field. Maybe export it using a semi-colon (`;`) as the CSV delimiter. Also, you will probably have to change the single quotes around `'bottom'`, `'left'` etc into double quotes but you can do that in Python before you call `json.loads()` on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work. It assumes a few things:

- that the separator in your CSV is a semi-colon, i.e. `;`
- that your CSV file is called `images.csv`
- that you want the cropped images output to a sub-directory called `output`
- that you have PIL/Pillow installed, though it could easily be adapted to use `pyvips`, `OpenCV`, `skimage`

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import re
import csv
import json
from PIL import Image

def cropImage(filename,coords):
    """Crop image specified by filename to coordinates specified."""
    print(f"DEBUG: cropImage({filename},{coords})")

    # Open image and get height and width
    im = Image.open(filename)
    w, h = im.width, im.height

    # Work out crop coordinates, top, left, bottom, right
    l = int(coords['left']  * w)
    r = int(coords['right'] * w)
    t = int(coords['top']   * h)
    b = int(coords['bottom']* h)

    # Crop and save
    im = im.crop((l,t,r,b))
    im.save("output/" + filename)
    return

# Create output directory if not existing
if not os.path.exists('output'):
    os.makedirs('output')

# Process CSV file - expected format
# heading;heading
# 00000001.jpg?sr.dw=700;{'right': 0.9, 'bottom': 0.8, 'top': 0.1, 'left': 0.2}
# 00000002.jpg?sr.dw=700;{'right': 0.96, 'bottom': 0.86, 'top': 0.2, 'left': 0.25}

with open('images.csv') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in csv_reader:
        fieldA, fieldB = row[:2]

        # Ignore header lines
        if not "jpg" in fieldA:
            continue

        # Strip trailing rubbish off filename
        filename = re.sub("\?.*","",fieldA)
        print(f"DEBUG: filename={filename}")

        # Replace single quotes in JSON with double quotes
        JSON = fieldB.replace("'",'"')
        print(f"DEBUG: JSON={JSON}")
        coords = json.loads(JSON)
        print(f"DEBUG: coords={coords}")

        cropImage(filename, coords)
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please remember to accept as correct answer if it works - click the hollow tick ✅ beside the vote count if it works. Thank you and good luck!